# IndexOutOfRangeException with "boundless" array?

Tags: c#, arrays, discord.net

First off, I just wanna take a second to assure all readers here that I'm not 'proficient' in C#, and thus an answer may be obvious (though I couldn't find one when searching).

I currently have a `EnumerableUtility` custom class to convert data types (usually Enumerables, though sometimes other data types) into an `object[]` array. I'm using a very sloppy method which essentially goes like this:

```
class EnumerableUtility
{
    private IReadOnlyCollection<object> data;
    public EnumerableUtility(IReadOnlyCollection<object> x)
    {
        data = x;
    }
    public object[] ConvertToArray()
    {
        object[] info = { };
        // Here's where I think the exception is raised
        foreach (object obj in data)
            info[info.Length] = obj;
        return info;
    }
}
```

Again, sorry for both horrible code, sloppy methods and slight ignorance, but I kinda want to sort this out into a proper 'array' for easier management. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Your "boundless" array is simply array with size 0 (zero) - like `new object[0]`.

Comment: Why not taking your IReadOnlyCollection<object> and using "ToArray()" on it?

Comment: You can retrieve `IReadOnlyCollectiion`s by index so please explain what you hope to accomplish by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `object[] info = { };` **HAS BOUNDS** its bound to ZERO (1 element). What you need to be doing is creating an array of the length of the incoming data Such as.

`object[] info = new object[data.Count];`

Next your array converting is incorrect you are setting the index to the `Length` of your array. This will always be out of range as arrays are *Zero Index Based* (ie the first array item is at the index `0` not `1`).

Finally if you were to change to `info.Length-1` for your index would mean that you will only ever set the *LAST* element on every loop. Which sort of negates the loop as you can simply assign the last element in the array to the last element in the collection. I have rewritten the method for you to convert the ReadOnly collection to an array.

```
public object[] ConvertToArray()
{
    object[] info = new object[data.Count];
    var i = 0;
    // Here's where I think the exception is raised
    foreach (var obj in data)
        info[i++] = obj;
    return info;
}
```

Now this will return an object array from your collection. However this is completly uneeded as it *reinvents* an very big wheel.

We already have an extension method on *every* `IEnumerable` to convert it to a typed array.

`var c = (object[])data.ToArray();`

One line (no extra methods) to convert your collection to an array.

1. [`Enumerable.ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [`List<T>.ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [`ArrayList.ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcyyh2hb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign a value to the element with index `info.Length`.
You should do something like this:

```
object[] info = new object[data.Length];
int i = 0;
foreach (object obj in data)
   info[i++] = obj;
```